# number of bound variables does not match number of tokens with sql "IN"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my PHP Code:

```
$roomNo = [1,2,8];

        $inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($roomNo), '?'));



        $totalRoom = $pdo->prepare('SELECT *
                                        FROM room
                                        WHERE categoryId = ?
                                        AND
                                        id NOT IN (' . $inQuery . ')
                                    ');

        $totalRoom->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        foreach ($roomNo as $key => $value) {
            $totalRoom->bindValue(($key+1), $value);
        }
        $totalRoom->execute();
        $totalRoom = $totalRoom->fetchAll();
```

Here is the error :

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
>   number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   /home/mohib/MEGA/PHP/Core
>   Project/Hotel-Room-Booking/controller/booking-check-form.controller.php:66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach($roomNo as $key => $value)... the first $key==0. $key+1 will re-bind categoryId.

Try this:

```
$totalRoom->bindValue(($key+2), $value);
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, no need for the loop if you're using IN(), you can just bind a string.

```
$roomNo = [1,2,8];
$inQuery = implode(',', $roomNo);

$query = "SELECT * FROM room WHERE categoryId = ? AND id NOT IN (?)";
$totalRoom = $pdo->prepare($query);

$totalRoom->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$totalRoom->bindValue(2, $inQuery, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$totalRoom->execute();
$totalRoom = $totalRoom->fetchAll();
```

To avoid mixing up indices you can also use named bind references:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE categoryId = :catId AND id NOT IN (:roomIds)";
$totalRoom->bindValue(":catId", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$totalRoom->bindValue(":roomIds", $inQuery, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Make sense, and worked perfectly! Thanks! Save my Day :D

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Second pair of eyes is all you needed, you would have spotted it tomorrow ;)

Comment: @Mohib I added to my answer, might be a simple way to do it

Comment: The ids in roomNo is not actually fixed, its from a result of another query, I used this approach at first but the result was wrong. Thanks again :D